# Flex header, content, footer layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following code, I want the content section to fill out to the point the footer hits the bottom of the screen.

EDIT: perhaps I should've been a bit more clear with the center align. The header and footer should be vertically aligned and all three items need to start from the left vertical line as shown below: [image]

How can I achieve this?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
    height: 92px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DCE5EB;
}

footer {
    height: 92px;
    border: 1px solid #DCE5EB;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.content {
    height: 700px;
    flex: auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class"content">Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `=` in your class `content`.
that's a simple typo.

And for your content. As you have static height for `header` and `footer`. 
You can give height of `100vh` to your content and reduce the height of `header` and `footer` plus not to forget to consider `border` i.e `2px` total.
And it will solve your problem.

EDIT: Vertical-Align can be achieved by giving `line-height` equal to `height`.
And to align it in your margin. You can either use, `margin` or `padding`, depending on your requirement.
Or you can even use

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
```

Remove `94px` + `94px` from your content

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 92px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #DCE5EB;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

footer {
  height: 92px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #DCE5EB;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 94px - 94px);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you didn't really explain why this works, the `vh` units measures relative to the browser **v**iewport **h**eight. This means it is fully responsive to all different screen sizes. Thus, if you set your containers to add up to `100vh`, they will exactly fill the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I still need to align the three sections. Please see the edited original post.

Comment: How are you getting those borders? Are you using margin?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to flexbox, you can also create this layout using CSS Grid.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ebagshk/)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 92px 1fr 92px;
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #DCE5EB;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem, ad corporis amet id aut rem similique culpa expedita placeat molestiae itaque quos, esse, adipisci in beatae nisi laboriosam eius!</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a flex solution. Also, your solution moves all the content to the left most edge of the parent div. I want them to be on the left most edge of a section in the middle of the screen. Please refer to the diagram in the original post.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty You'll need to clarify where the elements should align on the left. With grid you could easily create columns.

Comment: all three, header, content and footer. again, not the left of the most parent div, but the inner vertical line.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty I understand that you want all three elements to align to an 'inner vertical line' - however, I can't guess where that line should begin.

Comment: that is arbitrary