# Trying to create a flex based layout of header, content and footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this layout. The thin lines are within which all three sections must be bound by. The header and footer need to be vertically centered. And the the content should take the height till the footer hits the bottom of the viewport. Please note that the thin lines are only there to show the boundary... they shouldn't actually be in the code.

Work so  far:

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

header, footer, .content{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header, footer {
  flex: 0 0 92px;
}

.content{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it just might be me, but I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: which part don't you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flex header, content, footer layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165836/flex-header-content-footer-layout)

Comment: You asked this question earlier - if you need to, you can update your previous question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a margin and/or a width to the header, content and footer and align them to the center of the parent

- Added a nested element to the main containers for header, content and footer.
- Kept the width of the header, content and footer containers to 100% and gave a bottom border to them
- Added a width to the inner divs and aligned them in the center of their respective parents

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
  align-items: center;
}



header, footer, .content{
  margin: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width:100%;
}

header .section,footer .section, .content .section{
  height:100%;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red
}

header, footer {
  flex: 0 0 92px;
}

.content{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header><div class="section">Header</div></header>
  <div class="content"><div class="section">Content</div></div>
  <footer><div class="section">Footer</div></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want the border of header and footer to span the whole thing.

Comment: I have changed the answer for this.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I'd appreciate if you could run through the code real quick and explain it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `align-items` property to make vertical alignment inside header and footer

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: pink;
}

header, footer, .content{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header, footer {
  flex: 0 0 92px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```